# Query limitations in Firebase - .orderBy() error

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to fetch data from a collection in Firebase using this method:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('posts')                      
.where('datePublished', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: 1)
.orderBy('datePublished')
.orderBy('votes', descending: true)
```

The problem is that the posts are now being listed by order of 'datePublished' but instead I want the list of posts to be ordered by 'votes'.

If I remove the `.orderBy('datePublished')` line, I'll receive this error ([Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#limitations) is the documentation reference from that error message if it can be of more help):

```
error 'package:cloud_firestore/src/query.dart': Failed assertion: line 487 pos 13: 'conditionField == orders[0][0]': The initial orderBy() field "[[FieldPath([votes]), true]][0][0]" has to be the same as the where() field parameter "FieldPath([datePublished])" when an inequality operator is invoked. #0 _AssertionError._doThrowNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:51:61)
```

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Can you share the error message?

Comment: Yes I can share the error message but here's the doc reference from that error message if that can help more: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#limitations

Comment: error 'package:cloud_firestore/src/query.dart': Failed assertion: line 487 pos 13: 'conditionField == orders[0][0]': The initial orderBy() field "[[FieldPath([votes]), true]][0][0]" has to be the same as the where() field parameter "FieldPath([datePublished])" when an inequality operator is invoked. #0      _AssertionError._doThrowNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:51:61)

Comment: The error is hard to read, can you edit your question and share?

Comment: Your date published comparison to 1 seems a little strange, are you simply trying to avoid dates with a 0 value?

Comment: Yes in the example above I've simplified everything. The real query is a lot more complex

Comment: The orderby limitation is pretty specific but it crossed my mind that datePublished notEqual to 0 may allow you to do what you want...the documentation is not clear on that. I haven't tried it though.

Comment: @themag when you use each code `FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('posts').where('datePublished', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: 1).orderBy('datePublished')` and `FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('posts').orderBy('votes', descending: true)`, is the result the same?

Comment: The issue seems to be that since the query includes a filter with a range comparison (<, <=, >, >=), it requires a .orderBy() right underneath it to avoid the limitation error and in doing so, it overrides the other orderBy('votes') which is the one that I need to use for sorting for my specific case/scenario.

Comment: No the result wouldn't be the same for these two scenarios.

Comment: @themag I posted my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
Stream<List<T>> collectionStream<T>({
  required String path,
  required T Function(Map<String, dynamic> data, String documentId) builder,
  Query<Object?> Function(Query query)? queryBuilder,
  bool Function(T)? where,
}) {
  Query<Object?> query = firestore.collection(path);
  if (queryBuilder != null) {
    query = queryBuilder(query);
  }
  Stream<QuerySnapshot<Object?>> snapshots = query.snapshots();
  return snapshots.map((snapshot) {
    List<T> result = snapshot.docs.map((snapshot) => builder(snapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>, snapshot.id)).where((value) => value != null).toList();
    if (where != null) {
      result.where(where);
    }
    return result;
  });
}
```

---

```
class Model {
  Model(this.id, this.datePublished, this.votes);

  final String id;
  final int datePublished;
  final int votes;

  factory Model.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> data, String documentId) {
    final String? datePublished = data["datePublished"];
    final String? votes = data["votes"];

    return Model(documentId, datePublished ?? 0, votes ?? 0);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {"datePublished": datePublished, "votes": votes};
}
```

---

```
collectionStream(
  path: "posts",
  queryBuilder: (query) => query.orderBy('votes', descending: true),
  builder: (data, documentId) => Model.fromMap(data, documentId),
  where: (model) => model.datePublished >= 94,
),
```

Comment: So do I .......

Comment: No this wouldn't work my friend. A bit more detail: for 'datePublished', we're not using dates but instead using numerical values (1,2,3, etc.). Maybe using '1' was bad example but currently that number is actually 94. So we need to make sure that all posts with 'datePublished' with a value greaterThanOrEqualTo 94 are shown while all other posts with a lower number value are not shown. So it can't simply be isNotEqualTo: 0

Comment: Can you share more code like where is it used? I have a similar project and I want to see if my approach can be used on your code

Comment: Think you are gonna have to sort your dataset after the db call.

Comment: @GrahamD you are right :)

Comment: It's very difficult to share more code other than the example given as everything is clustered around several files and with pagination involved it would get very messy.  This might just be the limitations of filtering/sorting for Firebase but it seems so odd that such a simple query has such limitations. Everything would work perfectly fine with isEqualTo or isNotEqualTo but for my specific scenario, theres no other method & we must use isGreaterThanOrEqualTo. But when using this, we need another orderBy() right underneath which overrides the other orderBy() which messes up the entire query

Comment: I think you should sort after reading Firebase Firestore. I have a function like this which returns a `Stream<List<T>>` , is that what you need?

Comment: I'm not sure and not very familiar with it, I'll look more into it.